# What is the difference between starting ufw service and enabling ufw?

Tags: ufw

Is there any difference between the command

```
service ufw start
```

and the command

```
ufw enable
```

Answer (score 3):

When ufw is disabled, `service ufw start` will not work.  To check this, after you run `sudo ufw disable` then run `sudo service ufw start` it should show that the firewall is still inactive.

Example:

```
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo service ufw start
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo service ufw stop
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo service ufw start
terrance@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I believe so.

`ufw enable/disable` will actually enable or disable the `ufw` service. So it won't start even after a reboot, and using `service ufw start` won't start it either.

`service ufw start/stop/restart` just deals with the service power management. You can stop the service temporarily, restart it to reload some configs, or start it after stopping it.

`service ufw stop` may stop the service, but rebooting (and maybe relogging) will just cause it to start again.